# how to write the soql query with day in month and calender month date functions?

Tags: soql, query

I want to write below query for current month and day in month...
I tried like this way but facing error... Like...system.today:unexpected token

```
SELECT Name, Amount__c,Start_Date__c 
From Account a 
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(Start_Date__c) = :system.today().month() 
AND DAY_IN_MONTH(Start_Date__c)= :system.today().day()
```

Comment: You query doesn't generate an error for me in the Developer Console so for other situations where the date you are using isn't today keep the syntax in mind.

Answer (score 1):

`System.now().month()` is returning `DateTime` value where we can use in `Apex`. Seems like you need the `SOQL` to filter `Accounts` where the `Start_Date__c` is today. Try below code for `SOQL`

```
Select Name, Amount__c,Start_Date__c From Account a where Start_Date__c = TODAY
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, for the accounts created in the current month you can use the `THIS_MONTH` in the query.

```
SELECT Name, Amount__c,Start_Date__c 
FROM Account a 
WHERE Start_Date__c = THIS_MONTH
```

To know more about the soql datetime literals, see the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

Comment: But by looking at @sumit's code, it looks like he need to narrow down the filter to current date;`TODAY`